# Input raw sensor data into Google Android SDK Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, emulation, raw-data

I'm testing an APP using Google Android Studio/SDKs emulator and I want to input raw sensor data from another device into it. I'm basically turning the physical device and want it's accelerometer, GPS and other sensor data to be inputed into the Emulator and fed to the running APP.

Any idea how to do that??? :))

(I don't want to test the app on the physical device for other reasons so want to input raw inputs into the Emulator so it's fed to the running APP :))

Comment: Kind of like this: http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation but how does the application work and how does the emulator inject the sensor inputs.

Comment: To add on and be more specific of what's not working:(Running on a Mac with FireWall disabled)
-- I turned enabled USB Debugging (on both my phone and even the emulator just in case)
-- Turned on the SDKController Application
-- Ran the following command on my mac terminal:
$adb -d forward tcp:1970 localabstract:android.sdk.controller
- I then clicked on "Multi-Touch" on the application UI
- I turned on the emulator:
$./emulator -avd testapplication1 -screen multi-touch
- I also enabled showing the mouse pointer on the emulator
It shows "Emulator Connected" but nothing happens to the emulator

Comment: I can't move the screen like Google guys did here @3:40 http://www.2bdoc.com/video/google-i-o-2012-what-s-new-in-android-developers-tools-v639049.html